# Bidirectional async service - generated code vs example code mismatch on ::grpc::ServerAsyncReaderWriter

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm implementing a bidirectional stream grpc service in c++, and I have a mismatch between the protoc-generated code expecting these parameters (note the 2nd):

```
void RequestAddOrderChannel(::grpc::ServerContext* context,
                    ➡️      ::grpc::ServerAsyncReaderWriter< ::✂️::AddOrderResponse, ::✂️::AddOrderRequest>* stream,
                            ::grpc::CompletionQueue* new_call_cq,
                            ::grpc::ServerCompletionQueue* notification_cq,
                            void *tag)
```

and the example in https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.55.0/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc (also here https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/async/) in which they call that method passing the request R and the response W instead of the `ServerAsyncReaderWriter<R,W>`

from the example, line 101:

```
 service_->RequestSayHello(&ctx_, &request_, &responder_, cq_, cq_,
                                  this);
```

this results in a obv compilation error,

```
/tmp/order-manager/grpc/Server.h:91:49: error: no matching function for call to '✂️::OrderService::WithAsyncMethod_AddOrderChannel<✂️::OrderService::Service>::RequestAddOrderChannel(grpc::ServerContext*, ✂️::AddOrderRequest*, grpc::ServerAsyncResponseWriter<✂️::AddOrderResponse>*, grpc::ServerCompletionQueue*&, grpc::ServerCompletionQueue*&, void*)'

[..]
note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 6 provided
```

my question is: am I missing something? is the documentation outdated compared to the grpc versions I tried (1.54 and 1.55)? Should I create a ServerAsyncResponseWriter somehow and pass that one?

Comment: The example above is not for bidi streaming RPC. SayHello is a unary call.